# Laravel groupBy with select multiple field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I can select `country` and groupBy the result as following with an alias `total` :

```
Data::select('country', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
->groupBy('country')
->get();
```

The above code works well.
Here I can select only `country` filed, But I need to select aslo `name`, `positions` field,  How can I select multiple field here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like below settings and change code.

1. Open `config/database.php`
2. Find `strict` key inside mysql connection settings
3. Set the value to `false`

Use code below like

```
ModelName::groupBy('country')
->selectRaw('count(*) as total, country, name, positions')
->get()
```

Comment: This works, but I dont want to change strict mode to false. Any other way without changing the strict mode?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specify what error/exception you're getting but you can add additional column by doing

```
DB::table('table_name')->select([DB::raw('count(*) as total'), 'name', 'positions', 'country'])
->groupBy('country')
->get());
```

it is also likely you get an access violation exception which requires you to change sql_mode

Comment: It is still now error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation`

Comment: have you tried changing your sql_mode? SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: also you can disable only_full_group_by mode in database.php but that might lead to some security leaks in your app. Not advisable. I will advise your stick to the strict compatibility of groupBy